# Printing external URL without opening new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to popup the browser print option for an external URL without opening it in a new tab.

```
 <a href="##" onclick="printBGReport();" align="center">Print Report</a> <br/>
  <script>
    function printBGReport(){
        var W = window.open(document.getElementById('reportBGID').src);
        W.window.print();            
    }
  </script>
```

This code is working fine; however, it opens a new tab with the print option. Also, if I use chrome my current tab dies after opening the new one.

Comment: When I try to print an iFrame content, I got the error: Permission denied to access property "print" on cross-origin object

Comment: You can't access a third-party page due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 0x0 iframe to do this.  Something like (untested):

```
<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById("my-iframe");

iframe.contentWindow.innerHTML = "<strong>hello world</strong>";

iframe.print();

</script>

<style>
#my-iframe {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I got an error: iframe.print is not a function

Comment: Like I said, not tested.  It may be `iframe.contentWindow.print();`

Comment: When I try to print an iFrame content, I got the error: Permission denied to access property "print" on cross-origin object

Comment: If your iframe source is on a different domain (which that error suggests is the case), the solution I provided wont work.  That's why what I provided uses `.innerHTML` instead of `.src`.

You can do some trickery like `GET`ing the page source but at that point, just add a `.close()` after `.print()` to what you originally had.  It'll still open a tab, but it'll close it immediately after printing.

Comment: I followed your example with innerHTML and it says: TypeError: iframe is null